# Proving that a language is a CFL

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free

Assume that $L_1 \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is a CFL and that $y \in \Sigma^∗$ is a string.

I need to prove that the language $L_2 = \{x \in L_1 \mid x \text{ does not contain $y$ as substring}\}$ is a CFL.

I tried pumping lemma for CFLs, but it seems that is for disproving that languages are CFLs. I also tried to create a CFG for this language, but I'm having a hard time. I even took a look at the membership problem for CFGs.

Any ideas on how I would go about proving this?

Comment: Think *closure*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language  $L' = \Sigma^* y\Sigma^*$ is regular and, by the closure properties of regular languages, so is $\Sigma^* \setminus L'$. Then, by the closure properties of context-free languages, $L_2  = L_1 \cap (\Sigma^* \setminus L')$ is context-free (since it can be written as the intersection of a context free language with a regular language).

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to prove that a language is CF, even if in this case the solution proposed by Steven is shorter and more elegant, you can see if there is a PDA that accepts it, even though it my be tough not only to find it but also to formally prove it accepts every string of the language.